# Upload a new build to a "Ready for sale" version?

Tags: app-store-connect

I have an app in the Appstore that is 3.4 build 0.0.2 (Ready for Sale), but I found a small bug that I need too push out. It seems silly to update the version to 3.5 just for this small bug that we missed in testing.

(Update: I tried using @jksoegaard suggestion, but I get the below error:)
[image]

Is there anyway that I can remove the 3.4 from sale and simply create a 3.4 build 0.0.3 and submit this for review?

Answer (score 2):

Submit a new build with `3.4.1` as the short version value in the `Info.plist` file.

The value for [`CFBundleShortVersionString`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundleshortversionstring) **must** change between releases. The three digit [semantic versioning](https://semver.org) format is described in Apple's developer documentation and is widely understood beyond Apple's platforms:

> Given a version number MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH, increment the:
>
> - MAJOR version when you make incompatible API changes,
> - MINOR version when you add functionality in a backwards compatible manner, and
> - PATCH version when you make backwards compatible bug fixes.
>
> Additional labels for pre-release and build metadata are available as extensions to the MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH format.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to update the version number to version 3.5.

You can simply add the new build of 3.4 like any other update. Just ensure that the build number is higher than the previous builds of 3.4 you've added.

I.e. if you're currently selling version 3.4 build 2, then add the fix as 3.4 build 3.

You could also consider changing the version number to 3.4.1 or similar, but it is usually not a requirement.

Comment: I tried this but I am getting an error (I updated the original posting with a screenshot of the error)

Comment: Any other ideas?

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer, just write 3.4.1 as the version number to comply with that requirement.